# How to draw a combo chart in Python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataset that looks like this:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgx8n.png)

And I am wondering how to draw an area chart like the following in python using matplotlib:

[area chart example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzrXG.png)

Comment: Could you share the steps you've tried so far, and any code you've written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot(x,y1,y2,y3)

example code

```
x=numpy.arange(len(y1))
y1=[1,2,3,4]
y2=[4,3,2,1]
matplotlib.pyplot.stackplot(x,y1,y2)
```

Comment: Thank you, pretty straight forward.